# Проблема php - Добавление записи в MySQL через html-форму

Tags: php, html, mysql

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема в добавлении данный в mysql. Форма заполняется но при нажатии на кнопку ввод ни чего не добавляется в базу, и вроде даже не отправляется данные с формы в файл add.php. Помогите найти неполадки.

```
Код html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML-форма добавления новых книг</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="forma" aсtion="add.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="i"  /><br>
<input type="text" name="f"  /><br>
<input type="text" name="n" /><br>
<input type="text" name="o"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ввод"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

код php

<html>
<head>
<title>Программа добавления новых книг (файл insert_book.php)</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$i=$_POST['i'];
$f=$_POST['f'];
$n=$_POST['n'];
$o=$_POST['o'];
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","") or die ("Невозможно подключение к MySQL");
mysql_select_db("dog") or die ("Невозможно открыть таблицу с данными");

$query =  ("INSERT INTO prepod (idprepoda, familiya, name, otchestvo) VALUES ('$i', '$f', '$n', '$o')");
mysql_query ( $query );
if ($query == 'true') 
  echo "Добавлено в базу данных.";

mysql_close ($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: когда вместо переменных вот здесь VALUES ('$i', '$f', '$n', '$o'), пишешь вот так VALUES ('1', 'Иванов', 'Иван', 'Иванович') то запись добавляется

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)
[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: И еще почему то когда добавляешь в базу русские слова, то в базе вместо слов восклицательный знаки, как это исправить? в сравнение стоит cp1251_bin

Comment: вы на машине времени из конца 90х ?

Comment: После нажатия на кнопку ввод, данные не отправляются на файл php, а получается что страница обновляется и просто формы сбрасываются и все. php файл не открывается

Comment: да еще и ($query == 'true') отличное сравнение... Что бы этим хотите сравнить? у вас в $query лежит sql строка, которая ну никак не будет изменяться. может вот так: if (mysql_query ( $query )) ?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так попробуй:

```
$query =  ("INSERT INTO prepod (idprepoda, familiya, name, otchestvo) VALUES ('".$i."', '".$f."', '".$n."', '".$o."')");
```

А вообще переходи на `PDO`.

Comment: а покажи пример PDO или ссылку с примером кинь пожалуйста

Comment: да, проблема в том, что в одинарных кавычках переменная не будет обрабатываться )

Comment: @ivan9095
> а покажи пример PDO или ссылку с примером кинь пожалуйста

первая ссылка в гугле на запрос [PDO][1]


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: @ivan9095, Начните изучение PDO с этой [обзорной статьи][1]. Поймете принцип, а дальше к мануалам, ссылку на которые вам дал выше @abibock_un 

   [1]:Почему стоит пользоваться PDO